# Playing/Analyzing 20ms segments of WAV file using NAudio (or else)

Tags: c#, arrays, wav, binaryfiles, naudio

I'm having trouble using the NAudio component for the simple purpose I need.
I would like to have the **DATA stream only** inside my buffer (array) and then offset it for 20ms (and playing those segments in real-time.
I assume I can strip the Header but having problems achieving this.

I've tried using this:

```
WaveFileReader reader = new WaveFileReader(fullFileName);

             byte[] buffer = new byte[reader.Length];
            int read = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            short[] sampleBuffer = new short[read / 2];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, sampleBuffer, 0, read);
```

I can see that **sampleBuffer** contains the data (real pos-neg values, which I don't get if I'm using **byte[] sampleBuffer = File.ReadAllBytes(fullFileName);** ).

I'm using the following WAV file:

```
Pcm 8000Hz 1 channels 16 bits per sample
* Extra Size: 0 Block Align: 2 Average Bytes Per Second: 16000
* WaveFormat: 16 bit PCM: 8kHz 1 channels
* Length: 351360 bytes: 00:00:21.9600000
```

Comment: As far as I know, the `Read` method of `WaveFileReader` will give you only the actual audio data, i.e. it will strip the header information out. `File.ReadAllBytes` will give you the complete contents of the file, including the wav file header, so that's why you get different results. From your question I gather that you want the header info stripped out, so from what I can see your code should give you exactly what you want, so I'm a bit confused as to where you're running into a problem. Could you elaborate, please?